# Read srt file in java

Tags: java, file, srt

How can i read a srt file , do some operations in it and finally export it in srt format in JAVA?

i wanna do it to create a program that change the time of a subtitle.

att,

Diego Sabino

Comment: `srt` is a simple text file, read it as you would do with any other text file

Comment: right click on srt file -> open with notepad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that these programs already exists.

Search for: `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader`, `FileInputStream`.
Use them like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```